# What does "much reason" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've encountered sentences like *He gave not her much reason to do it*, and *there is much reason to celebrate in this new year* that use the expression **much reason**, but I am not sure what it means.

does it mean "very strong reason (in the sense of motive)"? Does it mean "many reasons"?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The first example as written is completely invalid (***gave not her much*** has to be ***gave her not much***). But it's not idiomatic to use negated ***much*** in such contexts anyway. We say *He gave her **little** reason to do it*. Also, *there is much reason to celebrate* [went out with the Victorians](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+much+reason+to%2Cis+good+reason+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - as that chart shows, it's *There is **good** reason to...* today. Are you seeing this in "Indian English" contexts? That's at least *possible*.

Comment: Whoops! I mis-read it as _He gave her not much reason_ because that is what I expected to see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means **a strong motive**.

**Reason** as an uncountable noun in this sense means 'good cause to do something', as distinct from **a reason**, a particular cause which could be one of several. If the writers had meant the countable sense they would have used **not many reasons.**

Comment: "The cookies contain *much* flour and *many* chocolate chips."